# android:ellipsize not working as intended

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

here is some code, I can replicate the bug even if I strip everything down to a simple TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="I AM VERY SMART I AM VERY SMART I AM VERY SMART"
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

I wish I could post a screenshot but SE is not letting me. what happens is that the text is truncated in the middle (as intended) but with a single dot (.) rather than a full ellipsis (...)

it does this on all lollipop tablets that I own (nexus 7 and nexus 9). other devices are displaying the ellipsis properly. I have researched the issue and found various comments about people getting the same problem, but no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as same as you.

I achieved my goal by setting:

```
width="85dp"
maxWidth="85dp"   // same as above
maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="middle"
android:singleLine="true"
abdroid:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"     
android:text="I AM VERY SMART I AM VERY SMART I AM VERY SMART"
android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: this truncates the text to the right by adding a fade effect. I could do that as a plan B, but what I need is a middle truncation with an ellipsis.

Comment: If change `ellipsize` to `middle` then what happen?

Comment: this is the same as I had before, apart from the focusableInTouchMode part which doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: try add the line `android:focusable="true`